# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int'

Tags: python

I'm writing a program in Python and i can't get past this exception

```
from cmath import sqrt;

a = int(input("Podaj pierwsza liczbe: "));
b = int(input("Podaj druga liczbe: "));
c = int(input("Podaj trzecia liczbe: "));

if a<=0:
    print("Nie można policzyc delty");
else:
        delta = sqrt(b*b-4*a*c);
        print("delta wynosi:",delta);

if (delta <= 0):
    print("Nie obliczymy miejsca zerowe");
elif (delta == 0):
        x = -b/(2*a);
        print("Miejsce zerowe wynosi:",x);
elif (delta >= 0):
        x1 = ((-b-delta)/(2*a));
        x2 = ((-b+delta)/(2*a));
        print("Pierwsze miejsce zerowe wynosi:",x1);
        print("Drugie miejsce zerowe:",x2);



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Rownanie kwadratowe.py", line 14, in <module>
    if (delta <= 0):
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int'
```

can you help me to solve this ?

Comment: Try using `from math import sqrt` (instead of `from cmath ...`) for a clearer indication of what your problem is.

Answer (score 6):

`sqrt` cannot yield a negative result. When passed a negative number you get a complex type, which doesn't compare to integers/floats, which explains the error message.

Now your *real* problem:

You have to test the sign of `b*b-4*a*c` (which is already the discriminant) and perform square root only if positive.

```
delta = b*b-4*a*c
...
if delta > 0:
   sqdelta = sqrt(delta)
   x1 = (-b-sqdelta)/(2*a)
   x2 = (-b+sqdelta)/(2*a)
```

There's no need to import `sqrt` from `cmath`. Import `sqrt` from `math` instead (which raises an exception when passed a negative value, otherwise returns a floating point value).